# concatenate String ArrayList element with String(this new String not belong to ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
animals.add("Asian");
```

I want to modify the element in animal ArrayList. Like this "Asian elephant"
without using animals.replace() method.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You want to replace "Asian" to "Asian elephant" in ArrayList animals?

Comment: without using replace . can I do that, like string concat

Comment: not using replace?, well just delete "asian" then add "asian elephant" back :)

Comment: `animals.remove("Asian"); animals.add("Asian elephant");`

Answer (score 4):

On your place I'd just make class Animal and then ArrayList of Animals. But if you don't want to, then you can do something like that:

```
animals.set(index, element);
```

where index is animal number, and element it's new name. The other option is to remove old animal name and add new one, for example:

```
animals.remove(o);
animals.add(e);
```

where o is old name, and e is new name.

Comment: what this guy said!  use inheritance / polymorphism